# How create *.bsd file in the UaModeler?

Tags: opc, open62541

Good day.

How can we export to `BSD` in the `UaModeler`?

I can only export to `XML` and `CSV`.

Answer (score 1):

'Export XML' should also generate the .bsd file.

Answer (score 1):

'Export XML' generates the .bsd file if you enabled dictionary nodes.
This can be done with a right-click on your model .ua and click on 'Update encoding nodes ...' and set the tick for dicitionary nodes.